# JSON decoding in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am currently working on a health application and i don't know how to decode this sample json using flutter. I want to extract "heartRateZones" list.

```
{
    "activities-heart": [{
        "dateTime": "2015-08-04",
        "value": {
            "customHeartRateZones": [],
            "heartRateZones": [{
                "caloriesOut": 740.15264,
                "max": 94,
                "min": 30,
                "minutes": 593,
                "name": "Out of Range"
            }, {
                "caloriesOut": 249.66204,
                "max": 132,
                "min": 94,
                "minutes": 46,
                "name": "Fat Burn"
            }, {
                "caloriesOut": 0,
                "max": 160,
                "min": 132,
                "minutes": 0,
                "name": "Cardio"
            }, {
                "caloriesOut": 0,
                "max": 220,
                "min": 160,
                "minutes": 0,
                "name": "Peak"
            }],
            "restingHeartRate": 68
        }
    }]
}
```

Please Help...
JSON is hosted at https://api.myjson.com/bins/g05ga .

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I reffere the official tutorials but i am not able to understand how to access nested lists.

Answer (score -1):

According [to the documentation](https://flutter.io/json/), you should use  `json.decode` and you will be able to extract what you want.

You can then use it somehow like this  `activities-heart.value.heartRateZones`

Comment: actually it was like `activities-heart[0]["value"]["heartRateZones"][0]["caloriesOut"]`

Comment: Great, hope that I helped you reach your goal anyway